# Accessing clientWidth and clientHeight of children elements of a Polymer element

Tags: polymer, google-chrome-devtools, polymer-1.0

I have the following **Polymer 1.0** element defined:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="us-states">
<style type="text/css">
  :host {
    display: block;
  }
  #div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  #svg {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
</style>
<template>
<div id="div">
</div>
<svg id="svg">
  <path d="M 10 10 L 30 10 L 20 30 z" fill="orange" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
</template>
</dom-module>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Polymer({
    is: "us-states",
    properties: {},
    ready: function() {
      var div = this.$.div;
      var svg = this.$.svg;
      console.log("Div width and height: " + div.clientWidth + " " + div.clientHeight);
      console.log("SVG width and height: " + svg.clientWidth + " " + svg.clientHeight);
      console.log("This width and height: " + this.clientWidth + " " + this.clientHeight);
    }
  });
</script>
```

The problem I'm seeing is that when the ready() function is executed in Chrome, all the clientWidth/clientHeight values are 0.

However, when I set a breakpoint at the end of the function and print the values manually, I get values I expect. Likewise, when I examine the values in the Scope Inspector debugger tool.

See screenshots (taken while at a breakpoint on the last line of the ready() function)
[image: values printed by above code and values from console]
[image: values in the scope inspector]

Interestingly, on Firefox I get the values I expect for this.client{Height, Width} and div.client{Height,Width} but zeroes for the svg element.

So my question is, what's the right way to access my custom element's children's width and height?

P.S. I'm running Chrome 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit) on Mac

Comment: When you log the values, the element and/or local children don't have layout yet. Have you tried checking the values in `domReady` instead of `ready`?

Comment: I'm using Polymer 1.0 which got read of the `domReady`. According to [their docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#ready-method) "The `ready` callback is called when an element’s local DOM is ready" also "Implement ready when it’s necessary to manipulate an element’s local DOM when the element is constructed.".

Comment: Sorry I meant `attached: function() { this.async(function(){ // check here. }) }`

Comment: Still the same result. Another thing I noticed, though, is if I examine the `svg`, `div` or `this` objects in the debugger before their properties are evaluated for the log statements, the values are computed and printed correctly in the log statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `this.$.div` and `this.$.svg` selector to take advantage of the automatic node finding. The `$$` method should be used for locating dynamically-created nodes.

You can find more infos in the official [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding).

Take a look at this [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/zilahutulu/edit?html,output) with the modified code.

Comment: Thanks! Were you able to get it to work using `$` instead of `$$`? I'm still seeing the same result, including for `this.clientHeight` and `this.clientWidth`

Comment: If you open the console in the jsbin I've linked, ypu'll get the correct values. I didn't have a chance to try it locally yet.

Comment: Yeah, your sample seems to work with `this.$$(...)` also

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, the this.async hint by @ebidel was a good starting tip, ultimately I found I needed to add a short (1ms) delay to the async to see the values.  I am not sure why, but the following worked for me.

```html
            attached: function() {
                this.async( function() {
                    console.log(this.clientWidth);
                }, 1);
            },
```